Protocol error: Mosquitto - RabbitMQ MQTT over TLS connection from local machine to server
Following rabbitmq tls support page I deployed a rabbitmq server on GCP using the following terraform script:
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "rabbitmq-ssl-network"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "static_ip" {
  name         = "rabbitmq--ssl-static-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "rabbitmq_instance" {
  name         = "rabbitmq-vm-ssl"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = "europe-west1-d"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-11"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOT
    #! /bin/bash
    sudo su <<EOF
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y docker.io
    apt-get install -y git
    apt-get install -y make

    # Clone tls-gen repository
    git clone https://github.com/rabbitmq/tls-gen tls-gen
    cd tls-gen/basic
    make PASSWORD=bunnies
    make verify
    make info
    ls -l ./result

    # Copy the contents of the result directory to /etc/rabbitmq/ssl
    mkdir -p /etc/rabbitmq/ssl
    cp -r ./result/* /etc/rabbitmq/ssl

    # Give permissions so that RabbitMQ can read the files
    chmod 755 /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/*

    # Create RabbitMQ configuration file
    mkdir -p /etc/rabbitmq/conf
    cat <<EOC | tee /etc/rabbitmq/conf/rabbitmq.conf
listeners.ssl.default = 5671
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 8883
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1883
mqtt.allow_anonymous = true
mqtt.default_user     = guest
mqtt.default_pass     = guest
mqtt.vhost            = /
ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_key.pem
ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
EOC

    # Start RabbitMQ container with SSL
    echo "Starting RabbitMQ container with SSL"
    docker run -d --name rabbitmq_mqtt -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 8883:8883 -p 1883:1883 -p 8443:8443 \
      -v /etc/rabbitmq/ssl:/etc/rabbitmq/ssl \
      -v /etc/rabbitmq/conf/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf \
      rabbitmq:3-management
    docker exec rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_mqtt
    docker restart rabbitmq_mqtt
    EOF
  EOT
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow_rabbitmq" {
  name    = "allow-rabbitmq-sll-server"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["5672", "15672", "8883", "1883", "8443"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow_ssh" {
  name    = "allow-ssh-ssl-server"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

output "rabbitmq_ip" {
  value = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
}

This generated the following files:
root@rabbitmq-vm-ssl:/etc/rabbitmq/ssl# ls
ca_certificate.pem          client_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_certificate.pem  server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_certificate.pem
ca_key.pem                  client_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_key.pem          server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_key.pem
client_rabbitmq-vm-ssl.p12  server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl.p12

I have a python paho mqtt script to publish data (I can add it if interested - it is also not able to connect), however first I want to subscribe a mosquitto client to listen on the published events, however am receiving a "Protocol error" message.
mosquitto_sub -h <public-ip-address> -t testssl/topic --cafile ca_certificate.pem
Error: Protocol error

When connecting via the TCP port (no TLS), the communication flows just fine.
Following rabbit-mq TLS troubleshooting I verified that:

I verified that the listeners are listed properly:

# rabbitmq-diagnostics listeners
Asking node rabbit@<random-string> to report its protocol listeners ...
Interface: [::], port: 15672, protocol: http, purpose: HTTP API
Interface: [::], port: 1883, protocol: mqtt, purpose: MQTT
Interface: [::], port: 8883, protocol: mqtt/ssl, purpose: MQTT over TLS
Interface: [::], port: 15692, protocol: http/prometheus, purpose: Prometheus exporter API over HTTP
Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: [::], port: 5671, protocol: amqp/ssl, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 over TLS


Verified TLS version:
# rabbitmq-diagnostics --silent tls_versions
tlsv1.3tlsv1.2tlsv1.1tlsv1



I checked the client(my laptop)-server(provisioned rabbitmq server) connection in the following manner:
root@rabbitmq-vm-ssl:/etc/rabbitmq/ssl# openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_certificate.pem -key server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
Enter pass phrase for server_rabbitmq-vm-ssl_key.pem:
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT


and see an error that might help someone knowledgeable:
openssl s_client -connect <static-ip>:8443 -cert client_certificate.pem  -key client_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem -verify 8 -verify_hostname rabbitmq-vm-ssl
verify depth is 8
Enter pass phrase for client_key.pem:
000C8AF401000000:error:8000003D:system library:BIO_connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:178:calling connect()
000C8AF401000000:error:10000067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:180:
connect:errno=61

Given that I dont do this everyday (and mostly dont know what I am doing) I wonder whether I am not missing something on the certificate part. Notice that the certificates are created using the tls-gen tool and I dont specify a port/ip address and expect that when connecting from my local machine to the gcp host the server will accept the connection.

Can you please check the ports in all of your commands (MQTT is listening on 8883 but you appear to be testing a different port, 8443).  Also please provide the full mosquitto_sub command line for the failing attempt (you specify ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert so will need to provide a client certificate/key).

And what happens if you explicitly set the port with -p 8883 on the mosquitto_sub command line?

@Brits thanks for the useful comment, I changed the ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert to false as I think its a better idea to first test just the CA cert. I am testing on 8443 as per the manual from RabbitMQ to test that SSL is working. When I tried 8883, I did not get to the ACCEPT part on the server side. Waiting to see if the fail_if_no_peer_cert false will run properly

@hardillb thanks for the comment, checking now - again I received protocol error:
❯ mosquitto_sub -h <static-ip> -t testssl/topic --cafile ./ca_certificate.pem -p 8883

Error: Protocol error

Sorry - when you said openssl s_client -connect <static-ip>... I assumed that static-ip was your server (but see now that you were just testing on your local PC). Please try running this against the server (port 8883) as this will check if a TLS connection can be made. Please also add the -d (debug) paramater to mosquitto_sub (some versions report "Protocol error" when the TLS connection fails) and edit the question with the full output.

The error from mosquitto_sub isn't very helpful and the error from openssl s_client seems unrelated. However, I think it fails because the CN of the certificate is incorrect.
You can verify by passing --insecure to mosquitto_sub, if that does the trick, regenerate the certificate with the CN set to the server's public IP.
Also, you can increase the verbosity by adding a -v to your mosquitto_sub command. That might produce a more useful error msg.

Thank you. I set the public IP and continued to have errors like:
~/workspace/experimentation/rabbitmq-mqtt-pubsub/ssl_authentication ··············  rabbitmq-mqtt  3.11  05:31:54 pm
❯ mosquitto_sub -h <public-ip> -t testssl/topic --cafile ./ca_certificate.pem -p 8883 -v -d

Client null sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
Error: Protocol error

Somehow I realised I am setting a password in the startup script using  make PASSWORD=bunnies. So now it only says make CN= and the connection is finally successful
